# How to make python exception handing for my app?

Tags: python, exception

I have finished a simple application to calculate the BMI, however, I need to create a couple of exception handlings in an another file, such like exceptions.py

These exceptions are: empty value exception, integer value exception, and email format exception.

Can anyone show me how to make these exception handlings in another file?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from exceptions import exceptions
import math , decimal

class BMI_Caclulator:

    def __init__(self,master):
        master.title = ('BMI Calculator')
        [distracting UI construction code omitted]

    def calculate(self):
        print('Name: {}'.format(self.entry_name.get()))
        print('Email: {}'.format(self.entry_email.get()))
        print('Age: {}'.format(self.age.get()))
        print('Gender: {}'.format(self.gender.get()))
        print('Weight: {}'.format(self.entry_weight.get()))
        print('Height: {}'.format(self.entry_ft.get())+ ' feets ' + format(self.entry_in.get())+ ' inchs' )
        print('BMI:' + str(self.calculate_BMI()))
        print('Comments: {}'.format(self.text_comments.get(1.0, 'end')))

        self.clear()
        messagebox.showinfo(title = 'BMI Calculator', message = 'Your information was successfully Submitted!')

    def clear(self):
        self.entry_name.delete(0, 'end')
        self.entry_email.delete(0, 'end')
        self.text_comments.delete(1.0, 'end')


    def calculate_BMI(self):
        self.inchs = int(self.entry_ft.get())* 12 + int(self.entry_in.get())
        self.BMI = int(self.entry_weight.get())* 703 /math.pow(self.inchs,2)
        return  self.BMI
```

Comment: You rarely need to create your own exceptions past what the python standard library provides, and even then it's probably an XY problem.

Comment: Thank you, I am new to Python, could you tell me which python library provides these general validations?

Comment: I believe it was written... "the python standard library provides"... outside of that, you are welcome to write `if some_value == ""` and `raise` your own condition to somewhere you `try`/`except` it

Comment: I think you are actually trying to validate the data from the input. You might want to look at https://github.com/alecthomas/voluptuous

Comment: Thank you @pekapa!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point Pythonista made is that you don't need to create new exceptions because they'll be created for you in most cases.

For example if you try creating an int from an empty entry, `int('')` will raise a `ValueError` by itself. The question is where you should handle the exception.
The function `calculate`is where exceptions are likely to happen so that's where to catch them, create a meaningful dialog box explaining the error and return to the main tk loop.  For example:

```
try
   print('BMI:' + str(self.calculate_BMI()))
except ValueError:
   # make a dialog box explaining that either the height or
   # weight were invalid numbers an ask them to try again
   return
```

It is extremely difficult to determine whether a string is a valid e-mail address. Since you aren't using it, if you tell them it's invalid you may well be wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I meant.